# Compiling an Apache Flink Example in Eclipse

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to run this 
[example](https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/02/09/streaming-example.html) where some DataStreams are being merged. I am using Eclipse for this and I added the Maven dependencies as specified [here](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html). Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, some classes are not being recognized (See picture).

[image: Classes not recognized by my compilter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you're linking to is written for Flink 0.9 and you're adding dependencies for Flink 1.0. The DataStream API has been heavily re-worked between these versions. You should either use dependencies for Flink 0.9.x or try a more recent example. For instance, you can try out the [WikipediaAnalysis example from the Flink v1.0 documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/quickstart/run_example_quickstart.html).